# geom_density and aes(y=..density..) producing different results

Tags: r, ggplot2, probability-density, density-plot

So it was my understanding that geom_density and putting `aes(y=..desnity..)` in a histogram do similar things - normalize the plotted data. My problem is that these to approaches produce different y-axis on the same data set for me.

With the code

```
ggplot(t3.tib.all, aes(Score, fill = Island)) + 
   geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), bins=50, position = 'identity', alpha=0.5) +
   labs(title="Task 3", x="Number of Seconds Inside Island
       (1 frame = ~0.2 sec.)", y = "Density") +
   xlim(0,50) +
  ylim(0,0.4)
```

I get the following: 
[image: Histogram plot]

and with the code

```
ggplot(t3.tib.all, aes(Score, fill = Island, colour = Island)) + 
   geom_density(alpha = 0.2, bw = 1) +  
   labs(title="Task 3", x="Number of Seconds Inside Island
       (1 frame = ~0.2 sec.)", y = "Density") +
   xlim(0,50)
```

I get [image]

Notice that on the first graph the y-axis goes to above 0.3 while on the second it only goes to 0.15. Also on the first graph the red bar is the highest, while on the 2nd graph it is much lower than the others.

What am I getting wrong here? Why the difference?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: the density plot and the histogram have different bandwidths - wider in the density plot (and of course different shape)

Comment: Would you also know how to change the binwidth of one to match the width in the other to make them comparable?

Comment: I mean, it's a not quite the same thing. `geom_density` is using a kernel density estimate, which `geom_density` describes as *"a smoothed version of the histogram"*. In the histogram, some number of bins are picked with an even spacing, and each bin is treated independently. With `geom_density`, observations are weighted based on how close they are to each point... things bleed together a bit. You could play with the `adjust` argument of `geom_density` (which is passed to `density`) to try to find something closer (start with `0.5`), but don't expect an exact match.

Comment: The *"smoothed version of the histogram"* is an OK analogy, but it's not actually how things are calculated.